# Select count(*) query from JdbcTemplate returns different value than running the query from SQL terminal

Tags: sql, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have this simple query :

```
sqlCount="  SELECT count(*)"+
            " FROM mytable "+
            " WHERE ID = ?"+
            " AND CANCEL_DATE IS NULL"+
            " AND LAST_NAME IS NOT NULL";




int count = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                sqlCount, new Object[] { id }, Integer.class);
```

called from Spring Boot.

There are no rows with the ID (150) passed in.
When running queryForObject, variable count comes up as 1 , while when running the same query from 
SQL Developer it comes up as 0!!

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: And you are sure that id is 150?

Comment: And can you check the executed SQL? logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=debug

Comment: @simon.The log shows the same query,there is no difference.The ID is also correct.

Comment: I created the exact same example and I'm getting 0. What are you doing before the count? Inserting data?

Comment: no,it's just it.After I do that check I continue with insertin rows

Comment: Can you provide a simple example on GitHub to show the error?

Comment: What is a type of `ID` column ? Is this a number, or maybe a varchar?

Comment: What class is `id`? Is it an `Integer` or a `String`? It sounds like the object is not being bound to the query as you would expect.

Comment: Just wondering ,  isn't it always better to assign the count to long instead of int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible causes

a) you are counting the number of rows returned (which is ONE) not the value inside that one row that is returned

b) you have an uncommitted insert transaction, which means SQL Developer cannot see it

But whatever the case, your comment where you said "After I do that check I continue with insertin rows", then your method needs to be revisited anyway.

The concept of: query first for existence, then insert if not, is basically flawed unless it is backed up via an appropriate database constraint, or similar locking regime. Because otherwise, you end up in the situation of:

Session 1 - check for existence, nothing found, we're OK, do the insert...
Session 2 - check for existence, nothing found, we're OK, do the insert...
Session 1 - commit
Session 2 - commit

and voila...you have multiple occurrences of a value when you were expecting only 1.

If you do indeed have an appropriate unique constraint/index defined, then you don't need to do the count check at all, because the insert will either work or be rejected as a duplicate.  Less code and no issue of data corruption.

Comment: ,thanks.it was an uncommited transaction.solved.As far as "query first for existence, then insert if not, is basically flawed" I'm doing the select and the insert in a serializable transaction.Would that be ok?

Comment: A serializable transaction operates in an environment that makes it appear as if there are no other users modifying data in the database, the database will be "frozen" at the point in time your query began. Your transaction sees the database consistently, at a single point in time. Side effects (changes) made by other transactions are not visible to it, regardless of how long it has been running....

But the key point - other transactions can STILL occur, and thus the issue still exists.